# wrapping byte array data with SWIG array_class

Tags: swig

I have a C function that returns an unsigned char * that can either be a pointer to a byte array (binary data representing a File..etc) or a pointer to an array of characters.  I'm currently using the SWIG `%array_class` that wraps all C functions that return an unsigned char pointer and creates a Java array utility (SampleArrayUtil.java) to handle the population and retrieval on the Java side.

My problem is that I also use wrap  the `unsigned char *` using: `%apply char * { unsigned char * };` so that I get an array of Strings on the Java side.  I don't want to wrap the `unsigned char *` return value (using `%apply char * { unsigned char * };`) when I get binary data back, I want to just have the byte array on the Java side.  I was thinking of creating another C function to handle the binary data, but I'm unsure how to wrap this new function as it will also return an `unsigned char *` (see `getValueFromRowAsByteArray`)

**C Functions:**

```
unsigned char * getValueFromRowAsStringArray(struct result_row *row, attribute_type type, int32_t *len)

unsigned char * getValueFromRowAsByteArray(struct result_row *row, attribute_type type, int32_t *len)
//*row* input param with data results, *type* input enum type for the data type being requested and *len* is an output param that contains the length of the data being returned.
```

**SWIG Interface File for Wrapping C Function Returning unsigned char * (array of char):**

```
%module Sample
%include "typemaps.i"
%include "stdint.i"
%include "arrays_java.i"
%include "carrays.i"
%array_class(unsigned char, SampleArrayUtil);
%{
#include "C_API.h"
%}
%apply char * { unsigned char * };
%include "C_API.h"
```

Comment: So you're looking to have different types returned on the Java interface from the same types on the C side - you want to selectively apply the typemaps? (Just checking we're on the same page before I write an answer)

Comment: @awoodland - yes that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply different type maps to the same types in different places in at least two ways.

Firstly you can change the active typemap with `%apply` or `%clear`, e.g.:

```
%module test

%include "stdint.i"

%apply intptr_t { unsigned char * };
unsigned char * test1();

%apply char * { unsigned char * };
unsigned char * test2();

%clear unsigned char *;
unsigned char * test3();
```

Gives three functions in Java with different return types, according to the active typemap.

Secondly you can also write more specific typemaps though, for example:

```
%apply long long { unsigned char * test4 };
%apply char * { unsigned char * test5 };
unsigned char * test4();
unsigned char * test5();
```

Only applies to `test4` and `test5` respectively - it matches on the type and the function name. In Java this results in:

```
  public static long test4() {
    return testJNI.test4();
  }

  public static String test5() {
    return testJNI.test5();
  }
```

For arguments you can match on the type and the parameter name in the function signature similarly.